# Lookup based on value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have the following schema in mongoose:

```
userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
        },
    team: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team',required:true
        }
})

teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }

   coaches: []
})
```

I want to join these collections, if user id is in `coaches` field, which is array of strings, in the team scheme.

After the join, I need to filter to get the users with a specific id in their `coaches` property.

For this reason, populate is not suitable here. I tried to use lookup, but can't find the right way to do this.
any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` the user id in `coaches` array
- `$addFields` to edit the `coaches` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of `coaches` array
- `$toObjectId` to convert string type `coaches` id to objectId type
- `$lookup` with users collection

```
let result await Team.aggregate([
  { $match: { coaches: "5a934e000102030405000001" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      coaches: {
        $map: {
          input: "$coaches",
          in: { $toObjectId: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users", // update to correct users collection name
      localField: "coaches",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "coaches"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P18QnRJ8NMk)

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Mongoosejs](https://mongoosejs.com/) and I don't think you need to do a lot, just make the proper relationship between them like

```
teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }

   coaches: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }] // where User is model name 
})
```

and here how to use them

```
Team.findOne({ name: 'team1' }).populate('coaches').exec();
// or with find
Team.find().populate('coaches').exec();
```

Ref:  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

**Update based on comment**

If you need to pass query and also projection then

```
Team.find().populate({
    path: 'coaches',
    match: { name: 'User1' },
    select: 'name -_id' // only user name, remove _id
  }).exec();
```

Ref: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

Comment: populate won't help because after that I want to filter based on the coaches field, so I need aggregate here.

Comment: `populate()` uses `$lookup` pipeline of `aggregation`, you may add filter in populate as well

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax of the filter after populate based on the populated?

Comment: I have updated the answer but I would like to suggest you to have look at the documentation for details

Comment: It won't help because I need to filter User to get all ids with a specific user id in their "coaches" field. in the ref you added, it says that you can not filter the first collection based on the populated field value.